# Gradle Task Dependencies

Tags: dependencies, task, gradle

How on earth can I do this in gradle: eg. want to use `HTTPBuilder` in a task.

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
 mavenRepo urls: "http://repository.codehaus.org"
}

configurations {
 testConfig
}

dependencies {
 testConfig 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0'
}

task someTaskThatUsesHTTPBuilder (dependsOn: configurations.testConfig) << {
     new HTTPBuilder()// <--this cannot be resolved/found??
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a class directly in your build script, you need to declare the dependency as part of the script's classpath in the buildscript { } closure. For example:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenRepo urls: "http://repository.codehaus.org"
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0'
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes - thanks!  Finally found that in the documentation after a while. I also put my database drivers in the same buildscript closure, but the class loader can't seem to find them?  Is there another trick to use?

Comment: Ah just found your post here Adam, thanks again i guess ;) http://www.mail-archive.com/user@gradle.codehaus.org/msg02450.html